# Javascript with techan.js mouseenter and mouseout events not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseout

I am not sure if I am messing it up, kinda new to javascript, what I am trying to do is showing some text when mouse enters a specific region and hide it when it leaves. You can find a fully working example of what I am trying to do at [this link](http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/69f49097e9bb5c0c6e4d).

Somehow I needed to encapsulate this code and what I did was something like below (anyways, just so you don't lose time, this code is almost a copy and paste from the link above, I just encapsulated it into a function and changed the way it consumed data):

```
function candlestickChart(targetContainer, data) {
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse,
        timeFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d'),
        valueFormat = d3.format(',.2fs');

    var x = techan.scale.financetime()
            .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

    var candlestick = techan.plot.candlestick()
            .xScale(x)
            .yScale(y);

    var trendline = techan.plot.trendline()
            .xScale(x)
            .yScale(y)
            .on("mouseenter", enter)
            .on("mouseout", out)
            .on("drag", drag);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select(targetContainer).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var valueText = svg.append('text')
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("class", "coords")
            .attr("x", width - 5)
            .attr("y", 15);


    accessor = candlestick.accessor();
    data = data.slice(0, 3500).map(function (data) {
        return {
            date: new Date(data.date),
            open: +data.open,
            high: +data.high,
            low: +data.low,
            close: +data.close,
            volume: +data.volume
        }
    }).sort(function (a, b) { return d3.ascending(accessor.d(a), accessor.d(b)); });

       var trendlineData = [
            { start: { date: new Date(2014, 2, 11), value: 72.50 }, end: { date: new Date(2014, 5, 9), value: 63.34 } },
            { start: { date: new Date(2013, 10, 21), value: 43 }, end: { date: new Date(2014, 2, 17), value: 70.50 } }
        ];

        x.domain(data.map(accessor.d));
        y.domain(techan.scale.plot.ohlc(data, accessor).domain());

        svg.append("g")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "candlestick")
                .call(candlestick);

        svg.append("g")
                .datum(trendlineData)
                .attr("class", "trendlines")
                .call(trendline)
                .call(trendline.drag);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Price ($)");

    function enter(d) {
        valueText.style("display", "inline");
        refreshText(d);
    }

    function out(d) {
        valueText.style("display", "none");
    }

    function drag(d) {
        refreshText(d);
    }

function refreshText(d) {
    valueText.text(
        "Start: [" + timeFormat(d.start.date) + ", " + valueFormat(d.start.value) +
        "] End: [" + timeFormat(d.end.date) + ", " + valueFormat(d.end.value) + "]"
    );
    }

}
```

After doing that, mouseenter and mouseout events stopped fireing, am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Console shows no error, it just don't work at all

Comment: Can you put this on jsfiddle?